# How to create and use custom primitives for Runtime API and Pallet?

Tags: struct

I'm trying to create a pallet that handles extrinsic and also runtime-api for the RPC endpoints. Since I plan to query storage items with RPC, I've created primitives for my pallet to use within my pallet and RPC.

I've taken a look at the [Beefy Pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/beefy/src/lib.rs) and its [primitives](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/beefy/src/lib.rs). I've implemented the code for my use case but got a bunch of errors about encodes and decodes.

I see that Beefy doesn't implement the traits specified in the error messages. Do I have to implement those? What causes these errors?

```
// ./profile/common/src/lib.rs

#[derive(Decode, Encode, Debug, PartialEq, Clone, TypeInfo)]
pub struct About<Hash> {
    pub option_one: Option<Vec<u8>>,
    pub option_two: Hash,
}
```

```
// ./profile/src/lib.rs

use pallet_profile_primitives::About;

...

#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn validator_set_id)]
pub(super) type ValidatorSetId<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, About<T::Hash>, OptionQuery>;
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `About: WrapperTypeDecode` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/estatetial/profile/src/lib.rs:27:12
   |
27 |     #[pallet::pallet]
   |               ^^^^^^ the trait `WrapperTypeDecode` is not implemented for `About`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Decode` for `About`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FullCodec` for `About`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `PartialStorageInfoTrait` for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageValue<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageValidatorSetId<T>, About<<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash>>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `About: EncodeLike` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/estatetial/profile/src/lib.rs:27:12
   |
27 |     #[pallet::pallet]
   |               ^^^^^^ the trait `EncodeLike` is not implemented for `About`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FullEncode` for `About`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FullCodec` for `About`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `PartialStorageInfoTrait` for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageValue<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageValidatorSetId<T>, About<<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash>>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `About: WrapperTypeEncode` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/estatetial/profile/src/lib.rs:27:12
   |
27 |     #[pallet::pallet]
   |               ^^^^^^ the trait `WrapperTypeEncode` is not implemented for `About`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Encode` for `About`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FullEncode` for `About`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FullCodec` for `About`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `PartialStorageInfoTrait` for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageValue<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageValidatorSetId<T>, About<<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash>>`
```

Comment: what versions of substrate are you using? are they the same as you are using as an example? and uniform for your project?

Comment: Also why look at Beefy, and not another pallet exactly?

Comment: I'm on the `devhub/latest` tag. Yes, they are all the same. And, I just found a solution. Will post it here soon. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Glad you figured this out! FYI if you are looking to be a parachain, `Bounded Vec` is the way to go, as it's required for parachains to have bounded storage items (base `Vec` is unbounded) - this then should not be annotated as such. https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/bounded_vec/struct.BoundedVec.html

Comment: Noticed that when `MaxEncodedLen` is required for `Vec`. Also, using `WeakBoundedVec` might be a workaround in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking through Substrate Frames and noticed that the frames using `Vec<u8>` have a macro `#[pallet::without_storage_info]`.

```
#[pallet::pallet]
#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
#[pallet::without_storage_info]
pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
```

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Default, Clone, PartialEq, sp_core::RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
pub struct About<Hash> {
    pub option_one: Option<Vec<u8>>,
    pub option_two: Hash,
}
```